# How to Append PDF files in iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, nsdata, nsmutabledata

I would like to append pdf files, i ll be getting NSData from server which i am saving as PDF, i want to add more data to existing PDF, i tried appending NSData which is appending the no.of bytes but if i save it as PDF then it only saves the appended part not the main part.

Example:

NSMutableData of existing PDF is firstdata
NSData of second PDF that i got from server is seconddata

now i have appended firstdata with seconddata and save it in a file this will only save the PDF part that is there in seconddata.

can anyone help me in solving this.

Comment: Because of the way the files are written, appending PDFs is more complicated than just adding two pieces of data together. You'll want to use CGPDFDocument and other Quartz APIs to accomplish this.

Comment: [Append an existing PDF file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15355168/1603234)