# Save out a new PDF with updates from users

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, pdf-generation

In my iOS app, I would like to regenerate an existing pdf into another pdf after the users are done annotating on the existing pdf.

My regenerated pdf should be an exact replica of the existing pdf but should have embedded annotations and highlights etc which can be opened and viewed on desktops as well.

I have done some research on this including the solutions proposed on other SO posts. I have tried libharu etc.

But somehow I am not able to convert an existing pdf into a replica pdf. I am able to add annotations to a new pdf I create using libharu.

Now my problem is to copy the existing pdf as is to my regenerated pdf. Any pointers will be much helpful.

Comment: [Append an existing pdf file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15355168/1603234)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that a library that can save back out a PDF with "true" annotations (those that can be hidden in Acrobat, for example) is not something that exists in a FOSS solution.

LibHaru, for example, **only** supports creating new PDFs, not editing or appending existing PDFs. From their homepage:

> At this moment libHaru does not support reading and editing existing
>   PDF files and it's unlikely this support will ever appear.

You can render the PDF on a page by page basis, and then re-save it with some additional information. [This S.O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333710/how-to-edit-a-pdf-in-objective-c) has a reasonable looking piece of code. That will save any "annotations" more as an image in the PDF itself, though.

You might try a paid library like [PDFNet](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/ios_pdf_library.html).

Comment: What about the ability to turn the annotations off or delete them when you are viewing the final pdf on desktop. That S.O question doesn't serve my purpose. I have tried all this to no avail. I don't intend to use a paid library.

Comment: So the challenge is - you need to add new elements to the PDF "data stream" for annotations that can be turned on or off. I don't know of any free libraries that allow for that on iOS.

Comment: Yeah Adam B that's the challenge. I am exploring various C/C++ pdf options available.

Comment: Post back an answer if you find a solution!