# Get actual coordinate of pdf in Webview when touch with Swift 3

Tags: ios, pdf, webview, swift3

I have successfully to load a pdf file from URL to a web view. I want to get the coordinates after touch on webview to sent it data to server to add some text to that position in server side. Problem is how can I get that coordinates when webview is zooming or scroll to page 2,3..
Could you please help me to solve the problem in Swift 3

**Here the code**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf")!
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))

        let webViewTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapAction(_:)))
        webViewTapped.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        webViewTapped.delegate = self
        webView.addGestureRecognizer(webViewTapped)
    }

    func tapAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // This always return the same coordinates in zoom or not zoom
        let point = sender.location(in: webView)
        print("======")
        print("x: \(point.x) y: \(point.y)")
    }
```

PS: I am a newbie in swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user3783161,

First of all, you can remove the following line, if you don't use any method from **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate**.

`webViewTapped.delegate = self`

To get the the actual coordinate when you touch the UIWebView, you need to get the location on **UIScrollView** and not from **UIWebView**.

```
func tapAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // This always return the same coordinates in zoom or not zoom
    // let point = sender.location(in: webView)
    // print("======WebView")
    // print("x: \(point.x) y: \(point.y)")

    // Get location frown webView.ScrollView
    let point = sender.location(in: webView.scrollView)
    print("======ScrollView")
    print("x: \(point.x) y: \(point.y)")
}
```

But you still have a problem, because the location is relative to the content size of the UIWebView and not to the PDF document.
I did not find the answer to this, but you can do a simple conversion between:

`PDF Paper Size vs. WebView Size`

Since the PDF must have this information (the pdf can be A4 / A3 / A5 / C1 / etc).